# Jquery ajax mvc multiple records insertion takes too much time

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, timeout

I have a MenuRole page which displays list of menu from the database.Users have to select a Role and corresponding menus from the page.All was going well but when i tried to save the data it is taking too long to save the data (approx. 50s).Some times `timeout exception` is coming.Maximum number of records to insert is `25`.

Is there any drawback in the way to save multiple records?

How can I save the data in less time??

**Delivery time of the browser**
[image]

**Button click event is**

```
$("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
        var form = $(this).closest("form");
        if (form.valid()) {
            isLoading(true);
            var formData = $('#frmRoles').serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "@Url.Action("Add","MenuSettings")",
                data: formData,
                datatype: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    isLoading(false);
                    if (data.message == "success") {
                        clearCheckBox();
                        toastr.success("Successfully saved the details.")
                    }
                    else if (data.message == "warning") {
                        toastr.info("Cannot save the data.RoleName already exists")
                    }
                    else {
                        toastr.error("Validaiton error.")
                    }
                },
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    isLoading(false);
                    toastr.error("Uncaught error.");
                }
            });
        }

        return false;
    });
```

**The controller is**

```
 [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Add(MenuRoleVM _vmMenuRole)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {                    
                //Check whether role already exists in RoleMenu table
                var _roleCount = _db.MenuRoles
                                .Where(m => m.RoleID == _vmMenuRole.RoleId).Distinct().ToList();
                if (_roleCount.Count > 0)
                {
                    return Json(new { message = "warning" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                }
                else
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < _vmMenuRole.MenuList.Count; i++)
                    {
                        MenuRole _menuRole = new MenuRole();
                        _menuRole.MenuID = _vmMenuRole.MenuList[i].MenuId;
                        _menuRole.RoleID = _vmMenuRole.RoleId;
                        _menuRole.CanAdd = _vmMenuRole.MenuList[i].CanAdd;
                        _menuRole.CanEdit = _vmMenuRole.MenuList[i].CanEdit;
                        _menuRole.CanDelete = _vmMenuRole.MenuList[i].CanDelete;
                        _menuRole.CanView = _vmMenuRole.MenuList[i].CanView;
                        _menuRole.TransactionTime = DateTime.Now;
                        _db.MenuRoles.Add(_menuRole);
                    }
                    _db.SaveChanges();
                    return Json(new { message = "success" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                }                   
            }
            return Json(new { message = "validationError" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Json(new { message = "Error: Cannot Insert" + ex.Message }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Comment: Turn off AutoDetectChanges like below code
context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;

It has to keep a track of all the changes to the context as the context gets bigger and bigger with lots of data

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Where should I put the following code in the controller section?

Comment: Is the save in controller taking too long, or the submit itself?
If it's in the controller, try `var _roleCount = _db.MenuRoles.Where(m => m.RoleID == _vmMenuRole.RoleId).Distinct().Count();` to get a count directly from database, instead of pulling all records to the list.
Also, do you have any other input elements, which are being submitted, but not used? If that's the case, maybe you are submitting more data than needed, which will take more time to upload to the server.

Comment: Just before the for loop where you keep adding the data to the context, add the code. Once you are done with the .SaveChanges(), make the flag back to true again.

Comment: @Robert all input elements are used for submission.

Comment: How many records are you adding? It should not take more than a few miliseconds per record.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I have mentioned it in the question, only upto a maximum of 30 records.I am testing the project in my local server(debug version) but my db connection is remote one.Will that make a difference?

Comment: Then some other issue is causing it to take that long.

Comment: :( @StephenMuecke  Is there a way to find out why is time delay happening?

Comment: I would start by creating a separate test method that just adds one `MenuRole` to the database and use [StopWatch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx) to time it.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks for your input mate .I uploaded the project to the main server and its working fine .I think the problem is that I was working with `local server + remote database connection` ,